# get users with custom fields

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

So I have an array of IDs of CPT author_title. I want to have a list of users, who has title in that array. I double checked in the database directly, only some users have custom field author_title.

However, my code returns an array of all users, instead of a few testing users.  Did I do something wrong here?

Here is the code

```
$args = array(
    'meta_query'    => array(
        'key'       => 'author_title',
        'value'     => $post_IDs,
        'compare'   => 'IN'
        )
    );
$authors = get_users( $args );
```

Comment: Will you please add the value of `$post_IDs` to your question? You can share the populating code, but the current value is really all that's needed. Additionally, please add the output of `get_user_meta( 'author_title' )` on a user you'd expect to be included in the result.

Answer (score 1):

Meta queries are arrays of arrays; try this:

```php
$args = array(
    'meta_query' => array( array(
        'key'     => 'author_title',
        'value'   => $post_IDs,
        'compare' => 'IN',
    ) )
);
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I tried that, but still get all users, unfortunately.